# How to read a specific part of a file

Tags: python, file, for-loop

I have a big file and will just post a lite piece of it:

```
World population in thousands
Source: United Nations, DEMOBASE

Country/ISO country code/UN Code/Population 1950/Population 2012
----------------------------------------------------------------
Afghanistan/AF/4/8151/33397
Albania/AL/8/1215/3227
Algeria/DZ/12/8753/36486
American Samoa/AS/16/19/71
Andorra/AD/20/6/88
```

My question is how do I read the 5 first rows, just the information before the information about the countries begin.

I tried someting like:

```
file=open("wordpop.txt","r")
for i in range[0:5]:
    rows = file.read()
print(rows)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range()` is a function, not a list. `range(5)` would work a lot better, but then you are just reading the file 5 times (four times reading an empty result).

Use `readline()` to read *one* line in a file, and a list comprehension to get the lines into a list easily:

```
with open("wordpop.txt","r") as infile:
    rows = [infile.readline() for _ in range(5)]
print(rows)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
for line in file.readlines()[:5]:
    print line
```

Comment: Yeah, but I think it looks cleaner/clearer so long as the file isn't absolutely huge